# Returning a div from .find and wrapping it in html

Tags: jquery, find

I have tried a few variations of this (.load)(.find)(.get), all of which fall down at the same point.
I am trying to pull information out of a specific set of DIVs from another page (this works fine).
Now the problem I am having is that the information it is pulling in is wrapped (correctly) in < li > tags.

I need some way of getting this information into a div and then making sure it is wrapped in < ul > tags to form the proper list.

My JS code is as follows:

```
$.get('pagetopulldatafrom.asp ', function (data) {
var posts = ' < ul id = "datalist" > ' + $(data).find('#testpull ') + ' < /ul>';
$('#result').append(posts)});
```

My HTML:

```
    <div class="more" id="readmore">
    <br />
    <div id="result">
    </div>
```

Many thanks

Comment: What does the `#testpull` element contain? `li` elements?

Comment: you want to display li in UL ? And what does this #testpull contains ? is it div ?

Comment: #testpull is a set of <li> elements I want to pull from one page onto another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of errors in your `posts` HTML string. Too many useless spaces that invalidate the code. Another wrong thing is that in `posts` string you do this:

```
'<ul id="datalist">' + $(data).find('#testpull') + '</ul>'
```

and it's wrong, because you're adding the result of `$(data).find('#testpull')` (that isn't the HTML string but a jQuery representation of your `<li>` elements) to your string. You could rewrite your code in this way:

```
'<ul id="datalist">' + $(data).find('#testpull').html() + '</ul>'
```

and it should works.

Usually, for simple HTML code I use strings, but when things get harder to handle with strings, I prefer (since jQuery is used here) to use all its power, so try this:

```
var posts = $('<ul>').attr('id','datalist').append($(data).find('#testpull'));
```

It's the same of your string but in a functional way.

Comment: Sorry, the spaces were there from a copy and paste. They don't appear in my code itself. That worked perfectly! Thankyou!

Comment: You're welcome. I've extended my answer to let you better understand what's gone wrong.

Comment: You could've also do it this way : `$(data).find('#testpull ').wrap('<ul id="datalist" />')`

Comment: @Lostdreamer but doing so you're going to [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) **each** `<li>` item with an `<ul>` tag, not the whole set of `<li>` returned by jQuery with an unique `<ul>`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ragnarokkr Heh... you are right, my bad, it should be wrapAll() instead. `$(data).find('#testpull ').wrapAll('<ul id="datalist" />')`